Drools Using Rules from Excel Files
I was trying to implement the drools BRE and for practice, I initially did it using a .drl file like this:
package com.example.droolstesting;
import com.example.droolstesting.Entities.Applicant;
rule "Suggest Manager Role"
when
    applicant:Applicant(
        experienceInYears > 10,
        currentSalary > 1000000 && <= 2500000
    )
then
    applicant.setRole("Manager");
end
rule "Suggest Intern Role"
when
    applicant:Applicant(
        experienceInYears<3,
        applicant.currentSalary<1000000
    )
then
    applicant.setRole("Intern");
end

Now, I want to do the same using Decision Table in excel.
This is my excel file:
rules.xlsx
Here's the DroolsConfiguration:
@Configuration
public class DroolsConfiguration {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    @Bean
    public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() {
        Resource dt = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com\\example\\droolstesting\\rules.xlsx", getClass());
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(dt);
        // KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        // kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/droolstesting/rules.drl"));
        return kieFileSystem;
    }
    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem());
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
        return kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);
    }
    @Bean
    public KieSession kieSession() {
        return kieContainer().newKieSession();
    }
}

Service Function:
public Applicant suggestARoleForApplicant(Applicant applicant) {
        kieSession.insert(applicant);
        int rulesFired = kieSession.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println("Number of rules fired: " + rulesFired);
        return applicant;
    }

It is not firing any rules for some reason. I get the Number Of Rules Fired as 0.
I know it might be a really basic issue but can someone please help as to why this is not working?
